# Updating Y-Axis of Highcharts line graph causes vertical line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am implementing a Highcharts line graph where I need to be able to drag points as well as update the y-axis of my chart. When I drag a point, and then update the y axis, a line is drawn from the original point to where I dragged: [Here is a picture of what is happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09nq9.png)

I'd really prefer to not have all these vertical lines, for some reason it seems to be duplicating the points because I also get some triangles when testing. Does it just leave the line but not actually update the point? To update the graph I am simply doing:

```
planChart.yAxis[0].max = newValueY;
$('.actualPlansPlot').highcharts(planChart);
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Here is the rest of the code:

```
var values = [...my values];
planChart = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        animation: false
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: startDates,
        crosshair: true,
    },
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}',
            style: {
                color: '#20709e'
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'title',
            style: {
                color: '#20709e'
            }
        },
    }],

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {

                    drag: function (e) {
                        // Returning false stops the drag and drops. Example:
                        /*
                        if (e.newY > 300) {
                            this.y = 300;
                            return false;
                        }
                        */

                        $('#drag').html(
                            'Dragging <b>' + this.series.name + '</b>, <b>' + this.category + '</b> to <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(e.y, 2) + '</b>');
                    },
                    drop: function () {
                        $('#drop').html(
                            'In <b>' + this.series.options.id + '</b>, <b>' + this.category + '</b> was set to <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + '</b>');
                    }
                }
            },
            stickyTracking: false
        },
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        },
        line: {
            cursor: 'ns-resize'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'title',
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> <b> {point.y} ' + trainingPlan.unit + '</b><br/>'
        },
        data: values,
        //draggableX: true,
        draggableY: true,
        dragMinY: 0,
        style: {
            color: '#20709e'
        }
    }]
}
$('.actualPlansPlot').highcharts(planChart);
```

It is pretty close to the example of draggable points online

Comment: Add your full code ,on share fiddle with issue

Comment: Without a JSFiddle I can only give you an educated guess. You're adding another point for the x-axis, instead you need to remove the existing value. Say you have at the x point 9/5 value: 10, you're also adding value: 20. So you have 2 points with 10 and 20, therefore the straight line. I would need a JSFiddle to demo my thoughts.

Comment: Agree @Jezzabeanz , I have added his code on fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/utnz2b9e/ with some static data

Comment: Here is the fiddle to demonstrate my problem:   jsfiddle.net/utnz2b9e/7  

Start by dragging the value for February up to around 25. Then enter 99 in the input below the plot and click update graph. When the graph is updated, a line forms on February

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

use following code :

```
$(document).on('click', '#updateYScale', function(e) {
var yValue = $('#newYValue')[0].value;    
        var chart =  $('.actualPlansPlot').highcharts();
        chart.yAxis[0].update({               
        max: yValue             
    });

  chart.redraw();
  });
```

See demo [fiddle with your issue's fix](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/utnz2b9e/12/)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. I have updated the fiddle to demonstrate my problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/utnz2b9e/7/

Start by dragging the value for February up to around 25. Then enter 99 in the input below the plot and click update graph. When the graph is updated, a line forms on February

Comment: @BradGoldsberry see my updated answer & fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/utnz2b9e/12/